# clsCommandButton: Microsoft Excel VBA - Run-Time Error '-2147024809 (80070057)'

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add dynamically CommandButtons to my Userform within the For-Loop. How can i get add new CommandButtons in the For-Loop?

```
 Dim CommandButtons(5) As clsCommandButtons
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim zaehler As Integer
    For zaehler = 0 To 4
        Set CommandButtons(zaehler) = New clsCommandButtons
        Set CommandButtons(zaehler).cmdCommandButton = Me.Controls(zaehler)
        Next
    End Sub
```

And This is my class:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cmdCommandButton As CommandButton

Private Sub cmdCommandButton_Click()
    Dim sFilepath       As String                       

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Filters.Add "TextFiles", "*.txt", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sFilepath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Cells(c_intRowFilterPathStart, c_intClmnFilterPath) = sFilepath
End Sub
```

I don't know how to handle this Error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Does the code compile? Do you have class named `clsCommandButtons`?

Comment: Yes it does compile. The class clsCommandButtons does exist and has the sub "cmdCommandButton_Click()" in it.

Comment: Also the Error occure in the line 'Set CommandButtons(zaehler).cmdCommandButton = Me.Controls(zaehler)'

Comment: Do `typename(Me.Controls(zaehler))` check it is a command button

Comment: I usually do this way `for each ctl in me.controls:if typename(ctl)="CommandButton" then......`

Comment: For typename(Me.Controls(zaehler)): Invalid Argument.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get the error because you're accessing a control that doesn't exist. Note that the controls are counted from `0` to `Me.Controls.count-1`, so probably your issue is solved with

```
Set CommandButtons(zaehler).cmdCommandButton = Me.Controls(zaehler-1)
```

But I guess a better solution is to name your buttons and assign them by name:

```
 Set CommandButtons(zaehler).cmdCommandButton = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & zaehler)
```

Comment: I changed the For-Loop zaehler = 0 To 4, but i still get the error

Comment: How many controls do you have on your page? And do you have only buttons? If you have only 4 buttons, they are numbered from 0..3.

Comment: Ah i see. I don't have any CommandButtons in my Userform. I want to add dynamically CommandButtons with this Code.

Comment: Is there a reason to create the buttons via code? While it is possible, usually it's better to place them once in design mode and then set the `visible`-attribute to show or hide them

Answer (score 0):

Define the `CommandButtons` collection as a `Variant`:

- `Dim CommandButtons(15) As Variant`, instead of  `Dim CommandButtons(15) As clsCommandButtons`.

In this `Variant`, you would put your CommandButtons. This is some minimal code, that would help you get the basics of what I mean:

`CustomClass`:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "I am initialized!"
End Sub
```

`In a module`:

```
Private SomeCollection(4) As Variant    
Public Sub TestMe()        
    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = 1 To 4
        Set SomeCollection(cnt) = New CustomClass
    Next cnt        
End Sub
```

---

From this small running code, you can start debugging further :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a() As clsCommandButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim c As Control

On Error GoTo eHandle

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "CommandButton" Then
        ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
        Set a(UBound(a)) = New clsCommandButton
        Set a(UBound(a)).cmd = c
    End If
Next c

Exit Sub

eHandle:

    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        ReDim a(0)
    End If

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

With a class as follows

```
Public WithEvents cmd As commandbutton

Private Sub cmd_Click()
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error for .cmd - Method or object not found. Do i need an additional reference?

Comment: No, that's just what I've called the command button in my class to sink, yours will be `cmdCommandButton `

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the Me.Controls(zaehler) part. zaehler starts at 1, but Me.Controls(...) starts at 0.

```
Set CommandButtons(zaehler).cmdCommandButton = Me.Controls(zaehler - 1)
```

would probably solve it